# How to use SearchView toolbar to filter database Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to implement a searchview to filter data from firebase database based on user input but when I try like this the result does not show like no data is updated.

I've tried by looking for some answers and tried it out but have not succeeded

this is my code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_resep, container, false);

    initFirebase();
    initRecylerView(view);
    setData();
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) mSearchMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Toast.makeText(context,query,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            searcDataFirebase(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void initFirebase(){
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    reference = database.getReference().child("jamu");

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                //instance object to get data
                model = postSnapshot.getValue(ModelResep.class);
//                    Log.e("DATA ",model.getBahan()+model.getNama()+model.getKhasiat()+model.getLinkGambar()+model.getPembuatan());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void searcDataFirebase(final String search){
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    reference = database.getReference();

    Query query = reference.child("jamu").orderByChild("NamaJamu").equalTo(search);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                //instance object to get data
                 model = postSnapshot.getValue(ModelResep.class);
//                    Log.e("DATA ",model.getBahan()+model.getNamaJamu()+model.getKhasiat()+model.getLinkGambar()+model.getPembuatan());

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

private void initRecylerView(View view){
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.rv_resep);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}

private void setData(){
    //instace object from lib firebase ui and set data
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelResep, AdapterResep>(

            ModelResep.class,
            R.layout.rows_jamu,
            AdapterResep.class,
            reference
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(AdapterResep viewHolder, final ModelResep model, int position) {

            //get id from click position
            final String id = getRef(position).getKey();

            //set data adapter from model
            viewHolder.setNama(model.getNamaJamu());
            viewHolder.setImage(context,model.getLinkGambar());

            //click listener for update data
            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetailResepActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id",id);
                    intent.putExtra("NamaJamu",model.getNamaJamu());
                    intent.putExtra("Bahan",model.getBahan());
                    intent.putExtra("Khasiat",model.getKhasiat());
                    intent.putExtra("LinkGambar",model.getLinkGambar());
                    intent.putExtra("Pembuatan",model.getPembuatan());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }
    };

    //set data adapter
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need in any array just create new method "firebaseUserSearch"
the copy your RecyclerView adapter and paste inside. use you databaseReference to filter it.

My FB structure is :

```
 BLABLA:
     Bars:
         01: 
            BarName: "Best bar"
         02:
            BarName: "The Worst bar"
```

And code is here:

```
  ....

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference ("Bars");

  .....


  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String searchText) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchText) {

            searchText = searchView.getQuery().toString();

            firebaseUserSearch (searchText);

            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}



private void firebaseUserSearch (final String searchText) {


    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Bar, ViewHolder>(

            Bar.class,
            R.layout.custom_row,
            ViewHolder.class,
       databaseReference.orderByChild("barName").startAt(searchText.toUpperCase()).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff"))
    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Bar model, final int position) {

  ....
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: You did. Voted up :)